# Why should this integrability condition be true?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

In [Markakis 2012](https://arxiv.org/abs/1202.5228), the following equation is derived,

$$ \partial^j K = 2 K^{jk} \partial_k \Phi\tag{12}$$

for scalars $K, \Phi$ and tensor $K^{jk}$ (Eq. 12). Following this, they state that a necessary but not sufficient integrability condition is,

$$ \partial^{[i}(K^{j]k} \partial_k \Phi) = \frac{1}{2} \partial^{[i} \partial^{j]} K =0.\tag{13}$$

where the square brackets indicate antisymmetrization (Eq. 13).

**Can anyone explain why this is true?**

Comment: Well, the middle expression vanishes because partial derivatives commute. Thus, by the first equality, the left-hand side must vanish. If the tensor $K^{jk}$ and scalar $\Phi$ does not obey this, the equality is violated.

Comment: It is in general not true without further assumptions about the metric tensor $g_{ij}$ (which raises and lowers indices).